# Python Tkinter program will not send data to my text file correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently trying to learn tkinter so building an application to save 3 variables, in this case username, password and website into a text file. Obviously actually using this method to save your passwords is an awful idea but its just for the sake of learning.

I have a problem where my application is running perfectly on the first go only. It takes in 3 variables and stores them in a text file following a button click. The problem is when I try to do this again I get an attribute error. I want to be able to append the file so I can fill in as many entries as I want without having to close it down and open it again.

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Here is my code.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter.messagebox

    def save_info():
        global username
        global password
        global website

        username = username.get()
        password = password.get()
        website = website.get()

        print(username,password,website)

        file = open("Software.txt","a")
        file.write("Username: " + username)
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("Password: " + password)
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("Website: " + website)
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("----------")
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()

app = Tk()
app.geometry("500x500")
app.title("Password Manager")
heading = Label(text="Password Manager",fg="white",bg="blue",width="500",height="3",font="10")
heading.pack()

username_text = Label(text="Username: ")
password_text = Label(text="Password: ")
website_text = Label(text="Website: ")
username_text.place(x=15,y=70)
password_text.place(x=15,y=140)
website_text.place(x=15,y=210)

username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
website = StringVar()

username_entry = Entry(textvariable=username,width="30")
password_entry = Entry(textvariable=password,width="30")
website_entry = Entry(textvariable=website,width="30")
username_entry.place(x=15,y=100)
password_entry.place(x=15,y=170)
website_entry.place(x=15,y=240)

button = Button(app,text="Submit Data",command=lambda: 
[save_info(),onClick()],width="30",height="2",bg="lightgrey")
button.place(x=15,y=290)

def onClick():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Password Manager","Data Saved Successfully")

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `save_info()` you overwrite the 3 varibales that were `StringVar()` so far. You have to find new variable names for them to store the strings.

```
def save_info():
    global username
    global password
    global website

    username_str = username.get()
    password_str = password.get()
    website_str = website.get()
    print(username,password,website)

    file = open("Software.txt","a")
    file.write("Username: " + username_str)
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("Password: " + password_str)
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("Website: " + website_str)
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("----------")
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

When your function(`save_info`) is called for the first time, the lines -:

```
username = username.get()
password = password.get()
website = website.get()
```

set the 3 tkinter `StringVar`s, to their string values, this is the reason that the next time you call the same function it throws an `AttributeError`, The easy fix to this would be to change these lines within the function, to store the value in 3 differently named variables, say `username_, password_, website_`.

The code then becomes -:

```
username_ = username.get()
password_ = password.get()
website_ = website.get()
```